# OR vs || conditions

Tags: c#, vb.net, conditional-statements

I just started using Vb.Net. I'm used to C# syntax. I know that I can do this in C# :

```
if (x | y)
//Test both 

if (x || y)
//Test both unless x is true
```

In Vb.Net how can I accomplish the same thing considering that :

```
If x or y Then
//Test both no matter what
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In Vb.Net how can I accomplish the same thing?

`OrElse`

The documentation is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx

The VB equivalent of `&&` is `AndAlso` by the way.

Comment: Ooo thanks. Helps the search when you know the words.. I don't remember how they were called . ( | Vs. ||) Do you know ?

Comment: Found it. Short Circuit Operator. Thanks again

Comment: Didn't know about this aspect of VB. Makes it sound ominous: `If YouDoThis() OrElse ThePuppyGetsIt()`

Answer (score 2):

In Vb.NET the equivalent is OrElse.

> Used to perform short-circuiting logical disjunction on two
>   expressions.

```
If x OrElse y Then
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2(v=vs.71).aspx